# Word ladder solution in Java using matrix

Tags: java, beginner, strings, edit-distance

> Given two words (start and end), and a dictionary, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from start to end, such that only one letter can be changed at a time and each intermediate word must exist in the dictionary. For example, given:
>
> ```
> start = "hit"
> end = "cog"
> dict = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
> ```
>
> One shortest transformation is `"hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog"`, the program should return its length 5.

The following is my implementation of Word Ladder problem. Can anybody review the code to compare its efficiency with other solutions?

```
package arrays;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordLadder {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    wordLadder();
}

private static void wordLadder() throws Exception {
    String source = "hit";
    String destination = "cog";
    Hashtable<Integer, String> dict = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
    dict.put(1, source);
    dict.put(2, "hot");
    dict.put(3, "dot");
    dict.put(4, "dog");
    dict.put(5, "lot");
    dict.put(6, "log");
    dict.put(7, destination);
    formHammingDistanceMat(dict);
}

private static void formHammingDistanceMat(
        Hashtable<Integer, String> dict) throws Exception {
    int mat[][] = new int[dict.size()][dict.size()];
    for (int[] row : mat) {
        java.util.Arrays.fill(row, 99999);
    }

    Set<Integer> keySet = dict.keySet();
    for (int i = 0; i < keySet.size() - 1; i++) {
        String mainString = dict.get(i + 1);
        for (int j = i + 2; j <= dict.size(); j++) {
            if (j == 7)
                System.out.println();
            mat[i][j - 1] = findHamming(mainString, dict.get(j));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(findShortestPath(mat, 0, 1,dict));
}

private static int findShortestPath(int[][] mat, int row, int col,
        Hashtable<Integer, String> dict) {
    if (col == dict.size()-1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (mat[row + 1][col + 1] == 1) {
        return 1 + findShortestPath(mat, row + 1, col + 1, dict);
    } else if (mat[row][col + 1] == 1) {
        return 1 + findShortestPath(mat, row, col + 1, dict);
    } else
        return 1 + findShortestPath(mat, row + 1, col, dict);
}

private static int findHamming(String mainString, String str)
        throws Exception {
    if(mainString.length()!=str.length()) throw new Exception();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mainString.length(); i++) {
        if (mainString.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the Word Ladder problem?

Comment: Hi, The problem statement is neatly explained here: http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-word-ladder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package arrays;
```

Wrong, unless it's your name and you've registered the top-level domain `arrays`. Seriously, use a personal package prefix, even for toy code.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
```

`Hashtable` still exists? :D Forget it, and use `HashMap` (it's about the same, but not synchronized and much more in use).

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> dict = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
dict.put(1, source);
dict.put(2, "hot");
```

That's what arrays are good for, you need no map here.

```
java.util.Arrays.fill(row, 99999);
```

Feel free to import it. Is `99999` enough? Sure, but the classical choice is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But this may lead to overflow, so sticking with a smaller constant is fine. Just declare the constant as

```
private final int VERY_FAR = 99999;
```

so that your code is not filled with essentially random numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keySet.size() - 1; i++) {
    String mainString = dict.get(i + 1);
        for (int j = i + 2; j <= dict.size(); j++) {
```

You shouldn't have started the numbering with `1`. Now there's `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`, pretty confusing. Actually, you shouldn't numbered the words at all, simply

```
List<String> dict = Arrays.asList(
    new String[]{"hot","dot","dog","lot","log"});
```

would do. Actually, you could stick with an array like

```
String[] dict = {"hot","dot","dog","lot","log"};
```

but lists are nearly always preferred.

You're computing the hamming distance of all word pairs. Google says

> The number of words in the English language is: 1,025,109.8.

which means some `1e12` pairs. You'd need a pretty smart algorithm to avoid this pairing, so let's forget it for now.

However, the problem is that you compute all the distances, while

- you don't really need them
- they don't really help

You don't need the distance, all you need is to know if two words are neighbors (i.e., a `boolean` instead of an `int`). But actually, the question is not "given two words, determine their distance", but "starting with `dog`, where can I go?". So what you need is something like

```
Map<String, Set<String>> neighbors;
```

and then a path-finding algorithm (which actually could make use of knowing the distance, but that's a different story).

```
if(mainString.length()!=str.length()) throw new Exception();
```

That's too brutal. Mathematically, returning infinity would be perfect. Returning some big number would be fine. Throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` or some exception of your would be fine, too.

However, it's good that you think about it. Doing nothing would be too bad (`distance("hot", "hotdog")` would be zero).